# Spring form field id with dot doesn't work well with jquery

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc

When I build a form I need to use a dots in `path` variable. When html is generated inputs has dots in ids. There is a problem with third party jquery plugins like validators. They doesn't work well with dots. Is there a way to change all dots into eg. "_".

Comment: I agree, it's slightly annoying. But good plugins should still handle it correctly. Don't forget to escape the `.` in your js code though.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be not to use automatic form binding, so instead of using `<spring:form/>` you might still use plain HTML tag `<form>` and handle it regular way. It all depends if you want to benefit from Spring's mechanisms like automatic form field binding and error handling. But if you are handling form validation with JavaScript and you plan to do it across the whole project, you might want to make that effort. What I usually do is to handle client side and server side validation with JavaScript (plain and AJAX), so I'm not using `<spring:form/>` at all.